# True column-mode (block-selection and editing) text editor solution?

Tags: software-recommendation, gedit, text-editor

In windows, I used to use a text editor called [crimson editor](http://www.crimsoneditor.com) which featured the best column-mode editing support I have yet to use.

When enabled via a simple <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut, selections could be made with the mouse or cursor keys and they would be visual blocks rather than wrapped-lines.

These selections could be deleted, moved, copied, pasted, and all of the operations just made sense. You could also just start typing, and you'd get a column of the characters as you're typing.

There are multiple ways of getting parts of the these features working separately discussed on [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042930) forum thread, but no one has yet to provide a solution that provides this all-encompassing and easy-to-use method.

If someone could point me to a gedit plugin where this work is actively being pursued, perhaps I could help with the coding myself. If someone is aware of a text editor that already provides this full functionality, I'd appreciate the info.  Running crimson editor through wine and the close-but-not-quite multi-edit plugin for gedit are the temporary solutions I'm 'getting by with' for the time being.

UPDATE (2012-11): I'm now a very happy user of [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).  It supports excellent column-mode editing and works on all three major OS platforms without any issue.  Highly recommended!

Comment: If you are familiar with emacs, emacs provides column editing support via many modes but requires getting used to (aka learning curve). I can detail if it will answer your question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[geany [image: Install geany]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geany)

is an integrated development environment that provides good column editing support which is worth checking out (an example [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/geany@uvena.de/msg00022.html))

Simply put, press down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Shift</kbd> while making selections to invoke column mode. One important limitation is that the edits in column mode are (as yet) not undo-able.

To achieve the same with the mouse, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while selecting. This actually works with most Scintilla-based editors (including SciTE and Geany).

Comment: I'm trying Geany and working with the column selection is quite nice.. it's almost there. Do you know if I make a block selection with the mouse?

Comment: Hold down Ctrl while selecting with the mouse.  This actually works with most Scintilla-based editors (including SciTE and Geany).

Comment: @JanC - Thanks for the input. I have updated my answer with this.

Comment: SciTE is also available on both Windows and Ubuntu, which you may find useful if you work on both platforms.

Comment: Works great on Fedora, too. I love geany!

Answer (score 11):

To edit columns, I use vi / gvim.  It takes a bit of learning to get used to vi, but in the end many people find this to be their preferred editor.

Specifically within vi you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> to highlight columns in visual mode, then you can edit it as you would expect.  I use this all the time for adding and removing comments, or indenting functions i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> (highlight a column) <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd> <kbd>ESC</kbd> will comment out that entire column.

Answer (score 6):

You do use the Eclipse editor. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> should do what you need.

Answer (score 5):

[nedit [image: Install nedit]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nedit) [image: Install via the software center]

I use **NEdit** all the time.

To install it using the terminal, use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nedit
```

Old school (Motif) but has tabs and is lightweight and simple. Has context highlighting included for a number of coding languages, and more can be added.
Pressing Ctrl while dragging with the mouse enables a block of text to be selected.
Then you can copy/paste as usual. Couldn't do without this feature now.

Comment: Can you select a block using just the keyboard?

Comment: Sure, with keyboard use Shift+Alt+arrows. I don't see column typing though (only column paste and indentation).

Answer (score 1):

Use a gEdit with gmate and plugins. You'll get the TextMate of Linux.

```
sudo apt-get install gedit gedit-plugins
cd ~/Downloads
git clone http://github.com/gmate/gmate.git
cd gmate
sh ./install.sh
```

With this "slight" modification gEdit really rocks.

Comment: But... gmate provides block editing?

Comment: Ctrl+PgDn/PgUp let you select the rows at once for block editiing. Also you can Ctrl+Left click to select variables to edit them at once.

Comment: @AndyB, what is exactly the name of the plugin that must be activatited? These shortcut keys don't work after installing gmate. (I am using gedit 3.4.2)

Comment: got gmate, but how to do column selection?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in emacs, and it's easy if you use the cua-mode. C-return marks the upper left of the rectangle. Then move the cursor to highlight the rectangular region.

- Here's a video that shows how to do it:
  http://vimeo.com/1168225
- And see section "CUA rectangle support" here:
  http://www.cua.dk/cua.html

The emacs column mode features are really cool. They go far beyond just copy/paste of rectangular text. Check out the video for a demo of how to simultaneously edit all the lines in the column! Very handy!

If you don't want to watch the video (or can't) here are the bare basics:

> CUA-mode's superior rectangle support is based on using a true visual representation of the selected rectangle. To start a rectangle, use [S-return] and extend it using the normal movement keys (up, down, left, right, home, end, C-home, C-end). Once the rectangle has the desired size, you can cut or copy it using C-x and C-c, and you can subsequently insert it - as a rectangle - using C-v. So the only new command you need to know to work with CUA-mode rectangles is S-return!

On Kubuntu 12.04 and emacs v24, [S-return] is CONTROL-RETURN (CTRL-ENTER) for me.

As already mentioned, Scite has this built-in (no plug-ins needed). It's very easy to use. And Scite is in the Ubuntu repos.

> Rectangular blocks of text can be selected in SciTE by holding down the Alt key on Windows or the Ctrl key on GTK+ while dragging the mouse over the text.

Answer (score 1):

Also Notepadqq can do this: they briefly present the feature [in their page](https://notepadqq.altervista.org). Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and select the "columns" you want by dragging (or also clicking, if you are holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) with the mouse. Release the buttons when you are done selecting columns, and start editing by typing, using arrow keys, copy-paste (a mouse click will cancel the multi-selection).

The points you select don't need to form a real column, it's an arbitrary number of cursors active at same time. When you copy-paste, the text is pasted cursor-by-cursor if the number of copied and pasted ones matches, otherwise every target cursor gets a full copy of the input.

Little nuisances: you can't de-select single cursors while keeping the others, and you can't use the keyboard to select them  (or at least, I don't know how to).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve it with the Gedit plugin multi edit. [This blog post](https://blogs.gnome.org/jessevdk/2009/11/15/new-gedit-plugin-multi-edit/) explains it.

1. Run `sudo apt install gedit-plugin-multi-edit`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to enter *Multi-Edit Mode*. It will reflect in upper right corner.
3. Make the desired selection, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Boom!, it's gone now, then you can edit multiple rows but in column mode.

Bonus: Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, when in *Multi-Edit Mode* and click at various points (which you want to edit at same time). this way you can edit multiple lines based on words.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this commands in terminal

```
sudo sed -i.backup -r '/^#\s?deb\s?(http|ftp|-src).*(partner|multiverse|universe)/s/^#\s?//g' /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y vim-gnome vim-doc

vim yourfile
```

In vim use:

```
ctrl-v ....... to select in mode column
j ............ to down
```

see:

```
 :help
```

Answer (score 0):

[KWrite](https://kate-editor.org/about/), [Kate](https://kate-editor.org/about-kate/) and [KDevelop](https://www.kdevelop.org/) also support this. It's a bit different in them in that column edit mode works not via modifier keys, but as a mode that you turn on and off. These three programs have different feature level but are based on the same editor component.