# What text editor for Linux has the following features?

Tags: text-editor

I have a text editor - Textpad - on a windows machine and it's a powerful text editor with very useful features, but it has no Linux port.

I was just wondering if I could find an equivalent that I could use for Ubuntu.

These features in particular are what I'm looking for the most:

- The ability to maintain block indents / block select / block editing
- Regular expression based search and replace, including multiline regex
- Macro recording feature to facilitate complex text transformations and data processing
- Line/Row sorting based on values in a specified column/position
- Bookmarking of lines, therefore allowing users to copy specific lines and then paste them to another document
- Support for editing multiple files, with tabbed document selection

Comment: possible duplicate of [True column-mode (block-selection and editing) text editor solution?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6451/true-column-mode-block-selection-and-editing-text-editor-solution)

Comment: Have a look at Geany http://www.geany.org/ It's in the repos.

Answer (score 3):

[VIM](http://www.vim.org/) has all of these features but I'm quite sure [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) has them as well.

Both exist for Linux / Windows / OSX.
and can be run as a desktop app or in terminal.

Be advised  they both have a high initial learning curve
But its well worth the effort!

Pick your poison.

Comment: As as side note, gVim may ease the transision to Vim

Answer (score 0):

My personal preferred editor is nedit. It is similar to gedit, but seems to have better better plugins on languages and more macro support.